# How does one make an object move with arrow keys?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to use a shape of some sort for now, but would like to replace it later on with a graphic, which I think is easy enough. But how would I use the arrow keys to control this and move it side to side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use event handlers - something like this:

```
private void Form_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{ 
   if (e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad0)
     {
       MyShape.Width ++ ;
     }
}
```

See here: for more examples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You might use the event handlers of `KeyUp` and/or `KeyDown`, or possibly you might need `PreviewKeyUp` and/or `PreviewKeyDown` instead.

In the handlers you can then update the position of your shape/ graphic.